# Sails how to use templates, server side

Tags: sails.js

I have already worked using Sails.js. But in that project we used it simply as an API. We had backbone on a client side.

In the new application I am planning to use Sails from bottom to top, and I have some things I do not fully comprehend.

I have views that use templates (EJS). In my controller I can call a view and pass it a model to render. That I understand. What I am dont fully understand is where do I put javascript files for a client in this scenario?

For example, lets assume that I have a view that has a input box and a button. I would want to have some javascript that controls that button and input (validation or whatever). Lets assume I put that code for input box and button  in a validation.js:
1. In what location do I put that file? Assets?
2. How do I include that file to be sent to client for execution? Do I include it in a template.ejs using normal < script > tags?

Comment: sails documentation explains it very clearly in [views doc](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the client assets should be placed into the `assets` folder.

All the includes are automatically binded by Grunt (when lifting the server) into the `layout.ejs` file, if you've put your css files into the `assets/styles` folder and your js files into the `assets/js` folder.